# Want to avoid "failed" message trying to install .NET 4.6.2 on Windows 10

Tags: .net, installshield

Our Installshield package for our product has .NET 4.6.2 as a prerequisite.  It installs that correctly when needed on Windows 7.  On a Windows 10 machine it cannot install it and shows the user a failure message.

From my understanding, .NET is already part of Windows 10 and thus doesn't need to be installed, but Installshield seems to try to do it anyway.  How can we stop Installshield from even trying? or at least hide the error message?

Comment: Your question body mentions Windows 10 but your title says Windows 8. Are you asking about a problem happening on both or just one of these versions?

Comment: What does error message say exactly?

Comment: Message "The installation of Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 Full appears to have failed.  Do you want to continue the installation?  Yes/No."  If you press "Yes" the rest of the installation is fine, but we would prefer not to scare the customer with a "fail" message.

Comment: We are seeing this on Windows 10, but I think the same might happen on Windows 8.  I'll update the title of the question.

Comment: More details: Windows 10 enterprise 2016 LTSB, version 1607

Comment: I may have figured this out.  In InstallShield program it is possible to edit the conditions for a prerequisite.  So I have removed "Windows 10" from the conditions for this one.  That does not make any change in the ISM file, but instead changes the PRQ file inside the InstallShield program directory (and thus affects all projects built on the machine).  Our test team will try it tomorrow.  If it works, I'll add this as the answer.